# Launching python script from javafx app

Tags: java, python, javafx

I want to launch some python scripts from a javafx app. 
To launch the scripts I use this code :

```
private String executeCommand(String command) {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;
    try {
        System.out.println(command);
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toString();
}

public void launchCommand(String inputDir, String outputDir) {
    String command = ".\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe ./test.py -i " + inputDir + " -o " + outputDir;
    String output = this.executeCommand(command);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

The problem is the script is launch by the javafx graphical thread so the line

```
p.waitFor();
```

will lock the javafx thread and so my gui stops responding...

I dont know how solve this problem...
Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Note that `readLine()` blocks too: I'm not sure you even need the `waitFor()` call here (though you do need to run this in a background thread).

Answer (score 2):

Just run the script in a background thread, and make sure you update the GUI back on the FX Application Thread, either using `Platform.runLater(...)` or by encapsulating the command as a `Task` and using the `setOnSucceeded` handler. The best practice here is to use an `ExecutorService` to manage the threads.

For example:

```
private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public void launchCommand(String inputDir, String outputDir) {
    String command = ".\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe ./test.py -i " + inputDir + " -o " + outputDir;
    Task<String> commandTask = new Task<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String call() {
            return executeCommand(command);
        }
    };
    commandTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
        // this is executed on the FX Application Thread, 
        // so it is safe to update the UI here if you need
        System.out.println(commandTask.getValue());
    });
    commandTask.setOnFailed(event -> {
        commandTask.getException().printStackTrace();
    });
    exec.execute(commandTask);

}
```

Comment: It's working, thanks! The script is now launched but it does not finish ... I'm sure that the script have no bugs. I think the problem come from the execution time of the python script (1-2 minutes) because whith a more basic script it's work perfectly. Do you have any idea to solve it ?

Comment: @PierreCarceller It should complete one way or the other. If an uncaught exception is thrown by the task, you can handle it with a `setOnFailed(...)` handler (see update). If it's just hanging and not exiting, then the only cause can be that the external process (python script) is not exiting.

Comment: I added the code you gave me but the behavior remains the same... I think the script doesn't finish because after 10 minutes nothing happened.

Comment: @PierreCarceller In your original version in the question, does the UI return to being responsive after some time?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: But it works perfectly with a basic script so I really think it comes from the execution time

Comment: @PierreCarceller Add some logging to the code and see where it's hanging. Did you see my comment under the question?

Comment: You were right, removing the p.waitfor() solves the problem. Thank you!  But I don't understand why it didn't work...

Comment: @PierreCarceller `waitFor()` blocks until the process is complete. The output from the process is already going to be piped out during that time. I'm guessing that you basically "miss all the data" by waiting for the process to finish first, so you end up waiting for data that's never coming.